# X-Frame-Options and frames

Tags: apache, iframe, frame

I did set X-Frame-Options DENY in the apache configuraiton file.

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
```

I can see that the  server response contain X-Frame-Options DENY at headers but the iframe on the page is still visible.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Best way i've found is to set it under your virtual host and if you're using drupal, make sure your "settings.php" has the following added to it:

$conf['x_frame_options'] = '';

Apache - virtual host set the following at the top of your definition (see below):

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/your_site_dir"

  SetEnvIf Referer "^.*?\.yourdomain\.(com|net)\.au.*?$" NO_X_FRAME_OPTIONS 1
  Header always unset X-Frame-Options env=NO_X_FRAME_OPTIONS
  Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" env=!NO_X_FRAME_OPTIONS

// Rest of config below...
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps! PS - this will also work with all un-supported browsers.

Comment: For future users: Make sure to edit the regEx in the SetEnvIf line to remove the "\.au" if you're not using an Australian domain name. FYI: Rodrigo's tip also works in the /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

This option isn't supported by every browser :

- IE8+
- Opera 10.50+
- Safari 4+
- Chrome 4.1.249.1042+ (Allow-From not yet supported)
- Firefox 3.6.9 (or earlier with NoScript)

Source : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx